# Bulletproof++ as generic ZKP ala SNARKs?

Tags: untagged

My understanding is that the primary usecase for BP/BP++ in elements is for range proofs for confidential transactions/confidential assets.

I haven't been able to get all the way through the BP++ paper yet, but it sounds like you could use it for doing arbitrary ZKPs for things like arithmetic circuits. If that's the case, could BP++ be a way to do non-interactive proofs for something like a rollup (the way snarks/starks are being used in other ecosystems)?